# Is there a trick/algorithm by which we can find all substrings possible in O(n) time

Tags: java, string, algorithm, substring

I have a brute force solution to calculate all substrings in an input string in O(n^2) time. Its takes long time when my input string is very long.

How can we find all substrings possible in O(n) time?

**I am only looking for count of all substrings where first and last character in substring is same. As you can see I am only returning count from function in my code below. I want to do it in O(n) time**

My brute force solution :

```
// I am calculating count of all substrings where first and last substring character are equal

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inputString = "ababaca";

    System.out.println(findSubstringByBruteForcce(inputString, inputString.length()));

}

private static long findSubstringByBruteForcce(String inputString, int length) {
    long count = 0;     
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= length - i; j++) {
            String str = inputString.substring(i, i + j); 
            if(str.length() == 1){
                count = count + 1;
            }else {
                if(str.substring(0, 1).equals(str.substring(str.length() - 1, str.length()))){
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

}
```

How can I optimize above solution and find answer in O(N) time? The input string can be extremely large (approx 10^6 length) and brute force runs in approx 20 seconds. I want maximum runtime to be under 2 seconds.

Comment: Are you looking for the actual substrings or the substring count? Are you looking for all substrings (including duplicates) or only unique substrings?

Comment: I am only looking for count of all substrings where first and last character in substring is same. As you can see I am only returning count from function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is ongoing programming contest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since substring identity is determined by the bounding indexes and not the content, it suffices to compute the frequency of each letter and then, for each letter, sum the term (frequency + 1) * frequency div 2, since each pair of letter positions with duplicates but without regard to order yields a counted substring.

Comment: Truly genius solution!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This method is the fastest possible if only the substring count (including duplicates) is needed. It should be O(N) assuming alphabet size ≪ string length.

Comment: Expound upon this.  This has promise, but has a lot of fluff to it.  Some maths would be nice.

Comment: why `(freq + 1)*freq / 2`? I think the correct formula for each letter is `C(2, freq)`, where `C(k, n)` is a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: @FalconUA The one-letter substrings count.

Answer (score 3):

This is fast O(n) but too much memory:

```
public static long findSubstringByCharacterMap(String s, int length) {
    long count = 0;
    long[] map = new long[Character.MAX_VALUE + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        count += ++map[s.charAt(i)];
    return count;
}
```

If the string only contains single byte characters, the size of `long[] map` can be 256.

You can rewrite `long[] map` by `Map<Character, Long> map`.  But it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which take constant extra space of array of size 256(maximum Ascii value is 255) & o(n) time complexity.

**Steps of Algorithm**

1. Create an array of 256.
2. add the current frequency of current element in ans & update the frequency of current element in string .
3. traverse whole string.
4. add string length in ans.

   here is my Java implementation of code tell me if i am wrong or i have miss understood question .

```html
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Solution
{
 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
 {
  String str="aabbab#cd#e";
  int[] array=new int[256];
  int ans=0;
  for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
      ans+=array[(int)str.charAt(i)];
      array[(int)str.charAt(i)]++;
  }
  ans=ans+str.length();
  System.out.print(ans);
  
 }
}
```

In this algorithm duplicate string will count.